# JPA query parent with only selected children

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate, jpa

I have these to classes `Parent` and `Child`

`Parent.java`

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "parents")
public class Parent implements Serializable {

private static final long serialVersionUID = 873222010704108510L;

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
private Integer id;

private String name;

@OneToMany(cascade=CascadeType.ALL)
@JsonManagedReference
private Set<Child> childs;

// getters and setters
```

`Child.java`

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "childs")
public class Child implements Serializable {

private static final long serialVersionUID = -6756632049453970501L;

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
private Integer id;

private String name;

@ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
@JsonBackReference
private Parent parent;

// getters and setters
```

Now my SQL DB has 2 children, `child1` and `child2` and they both have the same parent.

Now I want to get the parent and only child1 so in my `ParentRepository.java` I have the following

```
@Query("select p from Parent p LEFT JOIN p.childs c where c.name = 'child1'")
public List<Parent> getParent();
```

But when I call this I get back both children, this is because I see hibernate running 2 queries, which are below:

`Query 1` (the query I want)

```
/* select
    p 
from
    Parent p 
LEFT JOIN
    p.childs c 
where
    c.name = 'child1' */ select
        parent0_.id as id1_1_,
        parent0_.name as name2_1_ 
    from
        parents parent0_ 
    left outer join
        parents_childs childs1_ 
            on parent0_.id=childs1_.parent_id 
    left outer join
        childs child2_ 
            on childs1_.childs_id=child2_.id 
    where
        child2_.name='child1'
```

Then it runs this query - which I dont want cause it is getting all the children

```
 select
    childs0_.parent_id as parent_i1_2_0_,
    childs0_.childs_id as childs_i2_2_0_,
    child1_.id as id1_0_1_,
    child1_.name as name2_0_1_,
    child1_.parent_id as parent_i3_0_1_ 
from
    parents_childs childs0_ 
inner join
    childs child1_ 
        on childs0_.childs_id=child1_.id 
where
    childs0_.parent_id=?
```

How can I get it so the 2nd query is not run and I get the parent and only the child I want returned, I also want to return the parent even if there is no matching child which is why I have the left outer join

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### Option 1

Think in the other way, how about search on `Child` and get their `Parent`.

Add new constructors into the `Parent` class

```java
public Parent(Integer id, String name, Child child) {
    this.id = id;
    this.name = name;
    this.childs = new HashSet<>();
    this.childs.add(child);
}

public Parent() {
}
```

Change JPA query with below script.

```java
@Query("select new Parent(c.parent.id, c.parent.name, c) from Child c where c.name = 'child1'")
List<Parent> getParent();
```

Hibernate generates 3 SQLs for two `Child` record (More one query of all `Child` count)

```sql
Hibernate: select child0_.parent_id as col_0_0_, parent1_.name as col_1_0_, child0_.id as col_2_0_ from childs child0_ cross join parents parent1_ where child0_.parent_id=parent1_.id and child0_.name='child1'
Hibernate: select child0_.id as id1_0_0_, child0_.name as name2_0_0_, child0_.parent_id as parent_i3_0_0_ from childs child0_ where child0_.id=?
Hibernate: select child0_.id as id1_0_0_, child0_.name as name2_0_0_, child0_.parent_id as parent_i3_0_0_ from childs child0_ where child0_.id=?
```

**If you execute only one SQL** you can upgrade `Parent` class and Jpa query below.

Parent constructor:

```java
public Parent(Integer id, String name, Integer childId, String childName) {
    this.id = id;
    this.name = name;
    this.childs = new HashSet<>();
    Child child = new Child();
    child.setId(childId);
    child.setName(childName);
    this.childs.add(child);
}
```

Added new arguments into the jpa query

```java
@Query("select new Parent(c.parent.id, c.parent.name, c.id, c.name) from Child c where c.name = 'child1'")
List<Parent> getParent();
```

Hibernate generates a single query.

```sql
Hibernate: select child0_.parent_id as col_0_0_, parent1_.name as col_1_0_, child0_.id as col_2_0_, child0_.name as col_3_0_ from childs child0_ cross join parents parent1_ where child0_.parent_id=parent1_.id and child0_.name='child1'
```

#### Test

```java
@SpringBootTest
class DemoApplicationTests {

    @Autowired
    private ParentRepository parentRepository;
    
    @Test
    void contextLoads() {
        Parent parent = new Parent();
        parent.setName("p1");
        parent.setChilds(new HashSet<>());
        parent.getChilds().add(new Child("child1", parent));
        parent.getChilds().add(new Child("child2", parent));

        parentRepository.save(parent);

        parent = new Parent();
        parent.setName("p2");
        parent.setChilds(new HashSet<>());
        parent.getChilds().add(new Child("child1", parent));

        parentRepository.save(parent);

        List<Parent> parents = parentRepository.getParent();
        Assertions.assertEquals(2, parents.size());

        for (Parent parent1 : parents) {
            System.out.println(parent1);
        }
    }
}
```

Output

```
Parent(id=1, name=p1, childs=[Child(id=3, name=child1)])
Parent(id=4, name=p2, childs=[Child(id=5, name=child1)])
```

### Option 2

Fetch all children and manage `Parent` on java side.

```java
public interface ChildRepository extends JpaRepository<Child, Integer> {
    @Query("select c from Child c left join fetch c.parent where c.name = 'child1'")
    List<Child> search();
}
```

Hibernate generates single SQL.

```sql
Hibernate: select child0_.id as id1_0_0_, parent1_.id as id1_1_1_, child0_.name as name2_0_0_, child0_.parent_id as parent_i3_0_0_, parent1_.name as name2_1_1_ from childs child0_ left outer join parents parent1_ on child0_.parent_id=parent1_.id where child0_.name='child1'
```

#### Test

```java
@SpringBootTest
class DemoApplicationTests2 {

    @Autowired
    private ParentRepository parentRepository;

    @Autowired
    private ChildRepository childRepository;

    @Test
    void contextLoads() {
        Parent parent = new Parent();
        parent.setName("p1");
        parent.setChilds(new HashSet<>());
        parent.getChilds().add(new Child("child1", parent));
        parent.getChilds().add(new Child("child2", parent));

        parentRepository.save(parent);

        parent = new Parent();
        parent.setName("p2");
        parent.setChilds(new HashSet<>());
        parent.getChilds().add(new Child("child1", parent));

        parentRepository.save(parent);

        // search children
        List<Child> children = childRepository.search();

        // create parent hash map
        Map<Integer, Parent> parentMap = children.stream()
                .map(Child::getParent)
                .distinct()
                .peek(p -> {
                    p.setChilds(new HashSet<>());
                })
                .collect(Collectors.toMap(Parent::getId, p -> p));

        // add children manually
        for (Child child : children) {
            parentMap.get(child.getParent().getId()).getChilds().add(child);
        }

        // get parents
        Collection<Parent> parents = parentMap.values();

        Assertions.assertEquals(2, parents.size());

        for (Parent parent1 : parents) {
            System.out.println(parent1);
        }
    }
}
```

Output

```
Parent(id=1, name=p1, childs=[Child(id=3, name=child1)])
Parent(id=4, name=p2, childs=[Child(id=5, name=child1)])
```

### Extra

Fetch all `Parent` and fill matched `Child` records. We need some changes on `Parent` constructor pre-defined and a new JPA query that is `where` is replaced with `and` keyword.

**Parent Constructor:**
There is an extra `childId` control to avoid inserting a null child record.

```java
public Parent(Integer id, String name, Integer childId, String childName) {
    this.id = id;
    this.name = name;
    this.childs = new HashSet<>();
    if (childId != null) {
        Child child = new Child();
        child.setId(childId);
        child.setName(childName);
        this.childs.add(child);
    }
}
```

**ParentRepository:** There is no `where` key, because it restricts our result, we need just `and` instead of it.

```java
@Query("select new Parent(p.id, p.name, c.id, c.name) from Parent p left outer join Child c on c.parent = p and c.name = 'child2'")
List<Parent> getParent();
```

**Hibernate Query:**
There is a single query just executed.

```sql
Hibernate: select parent0_.id as col_0_0_, parent0_.name as col_1_0_, child1_.id as col_2_0_, child1_.name as col_3_0_ from parents parent0_ left outer join childs child1_ on (child1_.parent_id=parent0_.id and child1_.name='child2')
```

#### Test

```java
List<Parent> parents = parentRepository.getParent();
Assertions.assertEquals(2, parents.size());

for (Parent parent1 : parents) {
    System.out.println(parent1);
}
```

**Output:** We are searching `child2` and one record has this one, other is empty.

```
Parent(id=1, name=p1, childs=[Child(id=2, name=child2)])
Parent(id=4, name=p2, childs=[])
```

Comment: Hey, great answer, but there is another part to my question, as lets say I want to query where name='child3' but child 3 doesn't exist, I still want to return the parent, which is why I have the left outer join

Comment: Hi @iqueqiorio I have added an `Extra` part. I think it is what you want. I run for `child2`. There is one record that has `child2`, other does not have. So both of them returned. Also, for `child3` two records are returned and childrens' are empty.